# Need help creating a Quiz App for Android w. HashMaps & No Database

Tags: java, android, hashmap

My assignment is to create a simple Quiz app for Android. I am **NOT** looking for the code for this.. I am simply looking for someone to possibly lay out how to get started with this (pseudo-code ish).

The program is suppose to display **one term** and **four definitions**; one of them being the correct one. Once the user selects which one they think it is, the program will tell the user if it was correct / incorrect using a **toast** message.

Specs:

- The terms need to be randomly selected, and only displayed once per run. However the definition needs to stay in the pool of definitions for other questions.
- Definitions randomally selected (except the right one)
- Program ends if it runs out of terms to display
- Needs to use an **ArrayList** to hold collections of items, and a **HashMap** to hold name-value pairs.
- Must use Androids **logging mechanism** to log error messages (via try/catch statements).

If you can help me out by guiding me in the right direction, that would be great :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would (as always in object-oriented languages) start by mapping your problem to real-live objects. In your case, there would be two:

1. A `Question`-class which holds four answers, the question and offers a method to check if the given answer was correct.
2. An `Answer`-class which holds a single answer and whether it's correct or not.

As for your storage question, I wouldn't use a `HashMap` at all. Store the `Question`-instances in an `ArrayList` and use a [`Random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)-method to get a random question from your list.

In your `Question`-class, you would store all possible answers in another `ArrayList`. To randomize the order in which the answers are presented, you can use the [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)-method.

For the presenting part, have your `Question`-class return the question (string) and the four answers (strings) and put the into your widgets. To identify the answer given, you can use the `Answer`-instance (using the array-index is easier, but it is more error prone).

To check if the right answer was given, query your `Question`-classes `isCorrect(Answer)`-method and check if the given instance in the internal `ArrayList` is marked as the correct one.